# Prove $\lim_{(x,y) \to (-1,8)} xy = -8$ using only the definition.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I'm having problems trying to prove this limit using only the definition with delta and epsilon.

I need to see that:

$$ \forall\epsilon \  \exists \delta \ : \sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-8)^2} < \delta \Rightarrow |xy+8|<\epsilon$$

I want to make $|xy+8|$ look like the first half. I start by replacing $t=x+1$, so $x=t-1$ and $s=y-8$, so $y=s+8$. So I get:

$$ |(t-1)(s+8)+8| = |ts+8t-s-8+8| = |s(t-1)+8t| \leq |s(t-1)|+8|t|$$

Here I'm stuck, if I use that $\delta < 1$ then I can say that $t-1 > 0$ and since $|s(t-1)| = |s||t-1|$ then $|s||t-1| = |s|t-|s|$, which means I get:

$$ |(t-1)(s+8)+8| \leq |s|t-|s|+8|t| \leq |s|t+8|t| $$

I think I need to bound it by $||(s,t)||$, so I can add/substract and simplify, but I can't see how to do it. Any tips you can give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the inequality 
$$ |xy+8| \leq |s(t-1)| + 8|t| $$
you are on the right way. The idea now is that $s$ and $t$ should be very small since the limit takes $x$ to $-1$ and $y$ to $8$. Can you bound $|s|$ and $|t|$ in terms of $\delta$? After this you should be able to proceed to bound $|xy+8|$ in terms of $\delta$. Then you can decide how you want to choose $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$

Comment: I can bound either s or t by $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-8)^2}$, but I can only bound $st$ by $(x+1)^2+(y-8)^2$ which doesn't help me much. Also I don't think I can just bound the -s right?

Comment: Maybe if you bound everything in terms of $\delta$, it becomes more clear. Bounding $st$ by $(x+1)^2+(y-8)^2$ does help! How can you bound $st$ now in terms of $\delta$? On bounding $-s$: this is just the same as bounding $s$, since $|-s| = |s|$ (by bounding, I usually mean bounding the absolute value).

Comment: So is this right? $|st+(-s)| \leq |st|+|s| \leq ||s,t||^2+||s,t||$, but I don't see how that helps, it looks like $\delta^2+\delta$, but I can't choose $\epsilon$ with that, or can I?

Comment: That looks good, though you also need to take the term $8|t|$ into account when bounding $|xy+8|$. You should not choose $\epsilon$; this one is given. You have to show that for any $\epsilon$, you can choose a $\delta$ such that the implication holds. So eventually, you want to choose $\delta$ such that $|xy+8| < \dots\delta^2+\dots\delta \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: By adding the $8|t|$ bounded by $\delta$ I got it down to $\leq \delta^2+9\delta$, so is it enough to say for any $\epsilon$ choose $\delta = \epsilon^2+9\epsilon$? I didn't know you could just add terms inside epsilon, but If I can then that ends the proof.

Comment: The upper bound $\delta^2+9\delta$ on $|xy+8|$ is correct. Now given any $\epsilon > 0$, you need to choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta^2+9\delta \leq \epsilon$ (maybe solving the equality $\delta^2+9\delta = \epsilon$ helps). The choice $\delta = \epsilon^2 + 9\epsilon$ will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I'll keep trying, but I sorta understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different approach consider the following inequality. \begin{align} |xy + 8| &= |(x+1)(y-8) \, \, + 8x - y + 16 | 
\\ &= |(x+1)(y-8)\, \, + 8(x+1) - (y-8)|  
\\&\leq  |(x+1)(y-8)|+ 8|x+1| + |y-8| 
\\&= |x+1|\cdot|y-8|\, + 8|x+1| + |y-8|\end{align}

If you want to use the euclidean norm, then note that using the above inequality we have

\begin{align} \| (x,y) - (-1,8) \| < \delta_0 &\Rightarrow |x+1| < \delta_0 \text{ and } |y-8| < \delta_0 \\&\Rightarrow  | xy + 8 | < \delta_0^2 + 8\delta_0 + \delta_0.\end{align}

Therefore given $\epsilon > 0$, any $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta^2 + 8\delta + \delta < \epsilon$ will work.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to reach the same delta that I got after user158189 tips, one question though, can the last $\leq$ be an $=$?, The only difference I see is you distribute the abs over product.

Comment: @DamianPereira Of course, that should be an $=$, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks to you! I kinda get it now, for some reason it did not cross my mind that you could express $\delta$ as an addition of terms. I wanted to reach something like $a\epsilon$.

Comment: @DamianPereira No problem, from now on, it will! As always, practice makes perfect. :)